# Separate tables render together

Tags: html, html-table, alignment

Is it possible to have two separate tables in HTML have their columns aligned?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a width for the `<td>` elements on both and make their `overflow: hidden` so that things larger than the width don't change it.

Something like:

```
td {
   width: 50px;
   max-width: 50px;
   overflow: hidden;
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

as seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/H3327/).

Comment: Is there any way to do this without specifically setting the widths?

Comment: Not with pure CSS I don't think. You could make it happen with javascript, but it wouldn't be as clean.

Comment: Yikes I think I'd better stick with specifying the widths then. It may take fine tuning down the road but it's probably best.

Answer (score 0):

You could start from setting the widths of columns (whatever technique you use for it) exactly the same way and setting `table-layout: fixed` on both tables. There are still situations where cell contents force the widths to become different, but normally this should suffice.